# In which order should one study Geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Which is usually the order of Geometry study after studying calculus? Should I start with Differential Geometry? Maybe, Non Euclidean Geometry?

Comment: You probably need some topology before any of these.

Comment: It depends on your interests. Is algebraic geometry on your list as well?

Comment: Plain geometry. Planar then spatial. Next, analytical.

Comment: @Servaes sure, it is

Comment: @geocalc33 I didn't take abstract algebra, yet; it will be my next study subject.

Comment: @geocalc33 But can't I study Geometry and abstract algebra at the same time?